# Bucle do while en vba

Tags: vba

Tengo realizado un modulo que según que numero introduzca con el condicional if, me salga un mensaje u otro.

He creado una repetición con el bucle do while...loop, para que solo introduzcar del 1 al tres y sino vuelva a pedirlo,  pero no sale del bucle, me pide en cada vuelta que introduzca el dato. ponga 1 o 2 o 3

La variable la declaro como Variant o como String y da lo mismo, Porque el inputbox da como string y no como Integer.

Estoy buscando información de como se usa, pero creo que es asi, no veo el problema, ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Pongo el código:

```
Sub Escalado()

Dim Escalado As Variant

Do While Escalado <> "1" Or "2" Or "3"
MsgBox "Tienes que poner un numero del 1 al 3", vbInformation, "ENVIO CORREO PLANTILLA"
Escalado = InputBox("Tipo de escalado 1, 2 o 3", "ENVIO PLANTILLA", " SOLO INTRODUCIR UN NUMERO 1 - 2 o 3")

Loop

If Escalado = "1" Then
MsgBox "escalado n1"

ElseIf Escalado = "2" Then
MsgBox "escalado n2"

Else   
MsgBox "escalado n3"

End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu codigo tiene varios problemas...

Primero y principal

```
Escalado <> "1" Or "2" Or "3"
```

esto se traduce como Escalado distinto de 1 O 2 O 3, y si te fijas en el debuguer devuelve 3. porque realmente no se como lo esta entendiendo VBA, pero no existe hacer un distinto a 1 o 2 o 3 de esa forma.. lo que vos queres se escribe de la siguiente manera:

```
(Escalado <> "1") Or (Escalado <> "2") Or (Escalado <> "3")
```

Pero sin embargo, pusiste esto en un while, por lo cual, si escalado es 1 (y quieres que salga) le va a dar false el primero.. pero los otros dos le dan true...

entonces en realidad deberias hacer algo asi:

```
(Escalado <> "1") And (Escalado <> "2") And (Escalado <> "3")
```

Porque lo que estas buscando es que fallen los 3.. si uno no falla, va a dar falso y saldra del bucle.

Answer (score 0):

Según veo en el código, estás declarando la variable apenas inicia el procedimiento, esto encera la variable por lo que nunca sería igual algún valor.

Prueba con este código:

```
Dim miEscalado As String
Dim estado As Boolean

Sub Escalado()
    estado = False
    Do While estado = False
        Call Mensaje
    Loop

    If miEscalado = "1" Then
        MsgBox "escalado n1"
    ElseIf miEscalado = "2" Then
        MsgBox "escalado n2"
    Else
        MsgBox "escalado n3"
    End If
End Sub

Sub Mensaje()
    estado = False
    MsgBox "Tienes que poner un numero del 1 al 3", vbInformation, "ENVIO CORREO PLANTILLA"
    miEscalado = InputBox("Tipo de escalado 1, 2 o 3", "ENVIO PLANTILLA", " SOLO INTRODUCIR UN NUMERO 1 - 2 o 3")
    If miEscalado = "1" Or miEscalado = "2" Or miEscalado = "3" Then
        estado = True
    End If
End Sub
```